# how to add dynamic fields into joomla module

Tags: joomla, module, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I would like to add dynamic pair of fields into a Joomla module for configuration as follows:

field1(checkbox)-field2(menuitem)

field3(checkbox)-field4(menuitem)

```
            .
            .
            .
```

As many as rows my DB table has.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you want to have each input with different field number ? isn't it easier to have "group" of those 2 and just clone it with `name[]` where you can loop through them ?

Comment: OP wants dynamic number of fields I think. One for each menu item. Menu items can be added/removed in the menu editor so he cannot hardcode the fields.